# Checkout speed Toirtoise SVN on USB-Drive

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have installed Tortoise SVN and need to work across machines. One machine is not connected to the network and cannot be updated using the ssh-command. The repository is located on my main machine and the checkout to all connected machines was relatively quick: 2.4GB raw data ~ 1h. Seems long but this may be the processing\handshaking of the SVN.

For the isolated machine I wanted to checkout to an USB(3)-Drive. This turned out to be surprisingly slow. The current process runs 8h and only 100MB are checked out. On my machine TortoiseSVN does not require a lot of performance. Parallel to the checkout I copied the same folders on the USB-Drive and the speed was approx 2.5MB\s. This would mean the drive can support higher speeds.

Is there a special routine that excludes USB-Drives? Are there some restrictions in place that slow down the process?

I started my search looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785840/large-svn-repository-on-usb-3-0-key-how-to-speed-up-and-simplify) question. This was the reason I use my 'fast' Kensington 64GB USB3.2.

Comment: use a SSD drive with USB3-SATA adapter, that should be fast

Comment: I compared checkout on Samsung DUO USB3 thumb drive and SSD via USB adapter. on the thumb drive TSVN trunk checkout took 8min vs 2min on the SSD. So pick a SSD.